# Как разделить коллекцию на несколько других коллекций?

Tags: java, коллекции

Допустим, у меня 5 полок для книг. Так же имеется коллекция `(Collection<String>)` с названиями книг. Каким образом я могу разделить эту коллекцию, чтобы на каждой полке было приблизительно равное количество книг? То есть разделить эту коллекцию на 5 частей. Может подскажете методы, примеры алгоритмов?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Вы же должны понимать, что коллекция - это коллекция и чтобы ее разделить, нужно создать еще одну и заполнить ее, под вашим словом разделить, подразумевается перебрать и заполнить другие коллекции, нужными данными с нужным шагом и т. д. и т. п..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int countBookOnShelf = 5; //кол-во книг на полке
    List<String> books =  Arrays.asList("book1", "book2", "book3", "book4", "book5", "book6"); //список книг
    List<List> shelfs = new ArrayList<>(); //полки
    List<String> shelf = new ArrayList<>(); //полка наполняемая в данный момент
    for(String book : books){
        shelf.add(book);
        //если кол-во книг на текущей полке превысило максимальное возможное кол-во книг на полке, то начинаем заполнять новую полку
        if(shelf.size() == countBookOnShelf ){
            shelfs.add(shelf);
            shelf = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    if(shelf.size() > 0)  shelfs.add(shelf);
    System.out.println(shelfs);
}
```

Comment: он подошел по алгоритму, я убрал все лишнее и оптимизировал. Твой вариант намного лучше, но я еще не особо дружу с generics и stream, поэтому выбрал этот. Но главное это поставить дизлайк)

Comment: Мой вариант намного лучше чего?) стримами тут не выйдет, так как в форыче нельзя не финальные переменные использовать, такое вот ограничение.

Comment: А в чем проблема использовать цикл, за место метода? Я для примера форыч юзнул, чтобы показать вывод. И да - это не ограничение, а фишка замыкания, и это было бы странно, если бы переменная могла бы быть изменена в лямбда выражении.

Comment: Вообще сам всегда смотрю в сторону стримов, но  так как здесь один цикл мысли пошли в сторону foreach. По поводу ограничение или фишка вопрос, с какой стороны посмотреть.

Comment: С любой стороны посмотреть, тут происходит копирование экземпляра переменной во внутренний анонимный класс и если бы была возможность использовать не финальную переменную, то получилось бы так, что вы будете использовать устаревшую переменную, которая была создана в другое время и если бы вы даже и смогли бы внести изменения, то они бы были видны только в теле метода. Так - как это, локальная переменная, на свойства классов и методов это не распространяется. по этому вы слегкостью можете использовать и изменять свойства другого или текущего класса в котором определен метод с анонимом.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще сделать через `Stream`:

```
public static <T> Stream<Collection<T>> chunked(Stream<T> stream, int chunkSize) {
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> index.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
            .entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue);
}
```

А дальше использовать так:

```
Collection<String> str = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
Stream<Collection<String>> chunked = chunked(str.stream(), 2);
chunked.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

> [1, 2]
>   [3, 4]
>   [5]

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, можно как-то так.

1. Узнаём остаток от деления длины коллекции на кол-во коллекций, на которые надо оную разделить.
2. Запускаем цикл, в котором режем коллекцию на новые коллекции, с длинной, равной кол-ву полок `+1`, где `+1` добавляем столько раз, сколько у нас остаток в п.1 получился.

```
List<String> initialCollection = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
    initialCollection.add("" + i);
}
List<List<String>> resultCollections = new ArrayList<>();

int remainder = initialCollection.size() % 5;
int minimumCollectionSize = initialCollection.size() / 5;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int startIndex = i * minimumCollectionSize;
    int endIndex = (i + 1) * minimumCollectionSize;

    if (i < remainder) {
        startIndex += i;
        endIndex += i + 1;
    } else {
        startIndex += remainder;
        endIndex += remainder;
    }
    List<String> collectionPart = new ArrayList<>(initialCollection.subList(startIndex, endIndex));
    System.out.println(collectionPart.size() + "/ " + collectionPart);
    resultCollections.add(collectionPart);
}

System.out.println(resultCollections);
```

---

Проверить можно тут: https://ideone.com/u2UE4G

Answer (score 1):

Можно пойти через нахождение остатка и использования ф-ции subList:

```
final int stairsCount = 3;
List<String> books = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
int residue = books.size() % stairsCount;
final int booksInEach = books.size() / stairsCount + (residue == 0 ? 0 : 1);
List<List<String>> stairsOfBooks = new ArrayList(stairsCount);
for(int i = 0; i < stairsCount - 1; i++){
    stairsOfBooks.add(books.subList(i * booksInEach, i * booksInEach + booksInEach));

}
if(stairsCount != 0){
    stairsOfBooks.add(books.subList((stairsCount - 1) * booksInEach, residue == 0 ? books.size() : (stairsCount - 1) * booksInEach + residue));
}
```

Убедиться в правильности можно поместив следующий код:

```
stairsOfBooks.get(stairsOfBooks.size() - 1).forEach(System.out::println);
System.out.println("---");
```

В концы блоков `for` и `if`.